# EntryPoint, Pointer and Disassembling by means of a TDisAsm instance

Tags: delphi, exe, disassembly, portable-executable, entry-point

Using [DisAsm32](http://www.kbasm.com/download/disasm32.zip) by Russell Libby, disassembling a procedure/function/method is just a matter of passing a (consistent) Pointer to the `procedure TDisAsm.Disassemble(Address: Pointer; Size: Cardinal = 0);`.

So far, I have managed to disassemble any arbitrary procedure/method, even from a loaded external module (BPL/DLL) provided they are appropriately exported.

From the current process (The EXE image loaded by windows loader), I want to get a **valid pointer to the entrypoint**.

I want to come up with something akin to [IDR](http://kpnc.org/idr32/en/index.htm) (Interactive Delphi Compiler) provides through it's Code Viewer Tab but from the Exe running instance itself.

[image]

How can it be done? I'm not very comfortable with PE structures for the time being (but I am striving to, trust me) and wonder wether they are relevant for the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My own answer:**

I came up with the working solution as follows

```
function TForm1.GetEntryPoint: Pointer;
var
  DosHeader: PImageDosHeader;
  NtHeaders : PImageNtHeaders;
  OptionalHeader: PImageOptionalHeader;
begin
  DosHeader := PImageDosHeader(HInstance + 0);
  NtHeaders := PImageNtHeaders(HInstance + Cardinal(DosHeader^._lfanew));
  OptionalHeader := PImageOptionalHeader(Cardinal(NtHeaders) + SizeOf(DWORD) + IMAGE_SIZEOF_FILE_HEADER);
  //
  Result := Pointer(HInstance + OptionalHeader^.AddressOfEntryPoint);
end;
```

**Side Note:**

`SysInit.HInstance` is the same as `System.MainInstance`: My preference goes for it as it sounds more C/C++ and find that more meaningfull for the case.

[DisAsm32](http://www.kbasm.com/download/disasm32.zip) goes beyond the `call @Halt0` instruction when disassembling from the EntryPoint: It is designed to disassemble function/procedure/method and considers a `ret` instruction as the end.

**The moral of it:**

I will look for other more appealing disassembler such as [BeaEngine](http://www.beaengine.org/) and will keep the ball rolling.

Answer (score 1):

For PE structure reading/writing you can take a look at the open source JEDI library JCL, for example:
http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid38455E3CFDAF1F38C48DA3A295034E7015A4D01E.aspx?s=zip#L1810

The entrypoint of the running instance is "System.MainInstance"?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried to disassemble from `Pointer(System.MainInstance)` but were in vain. According the Embarcadero help it's the instance handle for the main executable: I presume it corresponds to the starting address where the Windows PE loader load the EXE image.